# Delay creation of instance in Simple Injector

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I am using Simple Injector in my project to hook up all the required dependencies, but  I cannot call `container.Verify` because it creates a `Singleton` instance for an **http configuration** before the actual first request

```
public interface IConfiguration { }
public class Configuration : IConfiguration
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        var httpRequest = currentHttpContext.Request;
        var httpRequestUrl = currentHttpRequest.Url;

        this.UriScheme = currentHttpRequestUrl.Scheme;
        this.UriHost = currentHttpRequestUrl.Host;
        this.UriPort = currentHttpRequestUrl.Port;
    }

    public string UriScheme { get; private set; }
    public string UriHost { get; private set; }
    public int UriPort { get; private set; }
}

public class ServiceA
{
    private readonly _configuration;

    public ServiceA(IConfiguration configuration) 
    {
        _configuration = configuration 
    }
}

public class ServiceB
{
    private readonly _configuration;

    public ServiceB(IConfiguration configuration) 
    {
        _configuration = configuration
    }
}
```

This is a basic example of the scenario. I currently have around **60** services all depending on `IConfiguration`

All the configuration needs to happen when the configuration class is created

This is what I do to register the instances in the container

```
var container = new Container();

//container.RegisterSingleton<IConfiguration, Configuration>();

var lazy = new Lazy<InstanceProducer>(() =>
    Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateProducer(typeof(IConfiguration), typeof(Configuration), container));

container.Register<ServiceA>();
container.Register<ServiceB>();

container.Verify(); // Creates configuration class --> not desired
```

As per [How can I skip verification of an object in the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688864/simple-injector-how-can-i-skip-verification-of-an-object-in-the-container)

> So the trick here is to trigger the creation of new `InstanceProducer` instances after the verification process

I know the workaround is using `Lazy<T>` and `InstanceCreator` but I cannot finish hooking my code correctly

**EDIT**

The `Configuration` class has no dependencies. The problem with `Configuration` is that it gets created as a `Singleton` on the `container.Verify` method call and at that time the `currentHttpRequest.Url` is not the actual url

I suppose I can move the configuration from the constructor to a method (e.g `GetConfiguration`) and do some refactoring but I am curious if delaying the instance creation can be achieved under the scenario of the question

Comment: Please show more details about the `Configuration` class of what part of it prevents it from being created and what dependencies does it have. Preferably, show some real code.

Comment: Besides, you read [this article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) that states that construction of application components, such as `Configuration` should not depend on anything that can fail, as is happening in your case?

Comment: @Steven: see edited question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained by Mark Seemann in [this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) article, injection constructors should be simple and reliable. They shouldn't do anything that might cause it to fail. Calling `HttpContext.Current` inside the constructor makes it unreliable, since this is something that might fail.

Besides this, your `Configuration` component now depends upon runtime data (the `HttpContext.Current` *is* runtime data), which is a sin, as explained in [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

The solution to your problem however is really simple and straightforward. Just change your `Configuration` class to the following:

```
public sealed class Configuration : IConfiguration
{
    public string UriScheme => this.Url.Scheme;
    public string UriHost => this.Url.Host;
    public int UriPort => this.Url.Port;
    private Uri Url => HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
}
```

Not only does this simplify things, it also removes the anti-patterns that you were applying which caused you trouble. Your constructor is now so simple, that it isn't even there anymore (can't get any simpler than this). And the runtime data is now only requested (from `HttpContext.Current`) after the object graph is constructed. This allows the container to verify its configuration reliably.

Comment: Thanks for your response Steven. I totally agree that I shouldn't have runtime data in the constructor... Your answer does solves the ```container.Verify``` problem but I am still curious about the dynamic of ```Lazy``` and ```InstanceCreator``` and how to apply those to bypass the ```container.Verify```

Comment: As per [Issue 227](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/227) this is a trivial thing to do but I cannot figure it out

Comment: @TMiNus that's a construct that clearly just complicates things in your case. As a matter of fact, the answer your question links to describes a very special exception where it is only justified by unchangable legacy code. Such construct should be used *only* in truly exceptional cases.

Comment: My point being that if I encounter an exceptional case in the future I cannot apply that construct and I do really like Simple Injector so I will start using it in all my projects moving forward thus I think is a matter of time before before I am faced with something like that scenario

Comment: @TMiNus if you encounter such truly exceptional case, please post a new question with all the details here or on Github. Each case needs its own analysis and deserves a could analysis and specific answer.